# WordPress Plugin menu position overwrite other item

Tags: menus, admin-menu

i've got a question. I created a plugin with a menu and i want to show this under the Dashboard menu-item. In some of my wordpress installations the dashboard item will be overwrited. How can i fix this?

My code to add the menu is:

```
add_menu_page('pluginname', 'pluginname', 'manage_options', 'pluginname-hello', '', 'dashicons-admin-site', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_submenu_page('index.php', __('Plugin Name from page', 'pluginname'), 'Plugin Name', 'manage_options', 'pluginname-hello', 'you_call_function' );
```

`pluginname-hello` - The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu).

`you_call_function` - The function to be called to output the content for this page.

More information:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/

Comment: I've done this correctly, but i want to place the plugin-menu beneath the Dashboard without overwriting other menu items.

Answer (score 0):

The code must be work. Add the code in functions.php and check result.

```
function admin_menu(){
    add_menu_page('pluginname', 'pluginname', 'manage_options', 'pluginname-hello', '', 'dashicons-admin-site', 2);

}
add_action('admin_menu', 'admin_menu', 99);
//add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'admin_menu'), 99); //for class based.
```

If you face the problem further change the priority of admin_menu hook like 99 to 1 or 2 as per your need.

Comment: Thanks this works! I've added: add_action('admin_menu', 'pluginname_menu', 99);
And now it doesnt overwrite another menu item :)

Comment: Btw, on some installations i still overwrite Dashboard.. :(

Comment: Explain a little bit or can you give screenshots. :)

Comment: I can't screenshot ATM, but the dashboard is on position 2 in the menu. When i install the Plugin it will totally overwrite the dashboard menu item, i dont want this as result: The Dashboard is not showing anymore.. I want the plugin to be under the dashboard menu item.

Comment: global $menu;
print_r($menu);
check your menu position. 
By the by the dashboard menu default position is 2 so you use you plugin position 3.

"When I install the Plugin" which plugin you mention.. your custom plugin or any community plugin.Then tell me the plugin name. Hope i will give you exact solution.